# How to avoid installing the configuration files of a swing application in every computer in the network?

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

I have a swing application that is installed in the server, and to access it, I have created a short-cut in every computer in the network, and it's working just fine. The application uses **jrxml** files to generate documents, and they are packaged in a folder called **Cycloplan** and its working fine, but I still have some technical issues, in which every time I make some updates in the configuration files, I have to go to every computer and paste the **Cycloplan** folder to it, so I am looking for a method to  avoid this operation when an update shows up. please help.

Answer (score 3):

Package the `.jrxml` files into Jars and deploy the lot using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  They will be updated automatically when the Jar is updated.

Comment: Thank you so much, but i think, i need a little more help, would you give a precise tutorial :D

Comment: The best advice I can offer in terms of tutorials is encapsulated in the See Also section, namely - [Java Web Start Technology - Overview](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/overview.html) Goes into the details of JWS deployment.
[Java Web Start Developer Guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html). - The Oracle guide for deploying rich client apps. using JWS. --  Go through those and you will gain a good idea on how to proceed.  Ask a more specific question, for a more specific answer.